# Rolling friction. Hard wheel and soft floor vs soft wheel and hard floor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, friction

Are rolling friction coefficients the same in the cases above?

I was only able to find the literature for the soft wheel / hard surface case.

My problem is the following.

I am trying a accelerate a wooden board with a mass of 60kg with 2 steel rolls with a diameter of 160mm. On each roll I am applying a force of 5400N. I am trying to figure out how fast can I accelerate before the wood starts to slip on the rolls.